# Deployment of Rails Application using Passenger and Apache2

Tags: apache2, rails

Is there anything special related to deploying a Rails application in Ubuntu using Passenger and Apache2?

I've installed passenger appropriately as indicated in the many instruction pages, but every time I add a new element within my sites-available directory (and subsequently a2ensite the file), I have no response at all.  In addition, passenger-status reports nothing.

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
   DocumentRoot  /var/www/html/mynewapp/public
   <Directory /var/www/html/mynewapp/public>
      Allow from all
      Options -Multiviews
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The webserver on which I must deploy the (sample) application is used purely for internal purposes, and has only a local IP addres (hence no domain crap, and why I have excluded the Servername directive).  Strange thing is that I don't even get an error in the apache error_log.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out myself; turned out it was not the apache configuration file, but rather that the application was not being registered with passenger.

To bypass this, I simply set the virtualhost to listen to a specific port (say, 123), and then updated the apache conf to listen on that port.  At that point, passenger-status reported the application in the pool.

Answer (score 0):

passenger via apache with the passenger module is what you want to do ?

The only way i know of is via `libapache2-mod-passenger`

I just post my conf, in my case for diaspora app.  ( afaik a server name is needed in a virtual host, at least it is its distinction from the other vhosts!?)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/diaspora/public"
    ServerName diaspora
        PassengerRoot /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.7
        PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby1.8
    #ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/

    Options +ExecCGI
    Options Indexes
    Options +FollowSymLinks


<Directory "/var/www/diaspora">
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/diaspora/public">
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: So if you were to access the webserver hosting this application by IP, what URL would you use in your browser?

Comment: The reason I ask is because prior to posting my question, I was able to access the directory of a FRESHLY made rails application from a browser as:

http://192.168.2.71/mynewapp

Yet, this dumped me into a directory index rather to the index page itself.  Subsequently accessing the public/ folder resulted in the typical rails 'Welcome aboard' page.  This, however, seemed little more than a static page since clicking the link "About your application’s environment", resulted in the error:

Not Found
The requested URL /mynewapp/public/rails/info/properties was not found on this server.